# How to change the label of a drop down field?

Tags: jquery, html

I know this is very basic.
I would like to use jQuery to change the label of a drop down field which was generated by Django.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="form-fields">
<table>
<tr><th><label for="id_Ap_m">Application method 1:</label></th><td><select name="Ap_m" id="id_Ap_m">
<option value="" selected="selected">Select an application method</option>
<option value="1">Aerial</option>
<option value="2">Ground Sprayer</option>
</select></td></tr>
</table>
</div>
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#id_Ap_m').html('New application');
});
```

My aim is to change 'Application method 1' to 'New application'. My approach is to select this label based on its id then change the text. However, my code does not work. It could because both the label and dropdown list have the same id (`id_Ap_m`), which was generated by Django.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I have a feeling you posted generated HTML, by Razor maybe.. Can you post the actual asp.net code or wherever it's coming from ? But overall yes, Neal is right instead of for="" it needs to be id=""

Comment: @Shenaniganz noooo keep the `for` that is exactly where it is supposed to be!

Comment: Well with the code you posted below yes, keep "for" :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your label has **no id**, did you try this?

```
$("label[for='id_Ap_m']").html('New application');
```

Comment: @tao.hong no problem ^_^ happy to help.